# Possible to customize the look-and-feel of child browser of PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

The default layout of ChildBrowser of PhoneGap is:
- Slide from bottom 
- A toolbar is on the bottom

Is it possible to customize the above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. check out the childbrowser xib it is a visual display of what the CB will look like. you can add and remove elements as you want. Note that if you are wanting to create elements that need to be interacted with you will need the corresponding objective c to do that.